# SymEnumSourceFiles get incomplete file names

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I was tring to use SymEnumSourceFiles to get the file name within the debugging module.But the file name as a parameter in the callback function seems incomplete. e.g. A file named"c:\program files\test\test.cpp" only showed "c:\program fi" in the FileName part of the PSOURCEFILE type parameter, and that's very wired.
Here is my code:

```
struct foo
{                                   
    static BOOL CALLBACK run( PSOURCEFILE pSourceFile, PVOID UserContext)
    {
        static TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH] = _T("");
        if (_tcscmp(szFileName, pSourceFile->FileName))
        {
            _tcscpy(szFileName, pSourceFile->FileName);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
};

    HANDLE hCurrentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    SymInitialize(hCurrentProcess, NULL, FALSE);    
    DWORD64 BaseOfDll = SymLoadModule64(hCurrentProcess,
                                        NULL,
                                       (LPCSTR)_bstr_t(lpszFile),
                                        NULL,0,0);
    if(!SymEnumSourceFiles(hCurrentProcess, BaseOfDll, NULL, foo::run, (PVOID)pCallBack))
    {       
        ATLTRACE(_T(__FUNCTION__) _T(" error:0x%x\n"), GetLastError());
    }
    SymUnloadModule64(hCurrentProcess, BaseOfDll);
    SymCleanup(hCurrentProcess);
```

Can anyone tell me where I go wrong please?
PS. When I simply replace SymEnumSourceFiles with SymEnumLines and change the callback function, the file name I got is correct.

Comment: Sounds like an off-by-two problem.  Unicode strings have twice the number of bytes.  You *really* need to get out of the habit of casting Unicode strings to (LPCSTR), that just can't work.  Presumably you do this elsewhere, explaining the problem.

Comment: Hi, Hans, it indeed an off-by-two problem, but it's not mine, it's MS's. If I didnot define DBGHELP_TRANSLATE_TCHAR, which tell the system to use the ANSI version of these functions(and do some adjustment with my callback function), I can get the complete filename, otherwise the name of the file is incomplete. I asked the same question in CodeProject, and one named Richard give me his test result which make me believe that(Also, I check what he did in my pc, and the result is the same as he told).

Comment: And again, thanks for your patient answer.

Comment: I'll buy that.  Nobody uses it so this doesn't get tested.  Just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a bug with SymEnumSymbols where symbol name was not zero terminated, maybe this one is related. Try zeroing out the filename after copying it (`pSourceFile->FileName[0] = 0;`).

Answer (score 0):

Try ANSI version of SymEnumSourceFiles. There seems to be a bug in SymEnumSourceFilesW function.